# I have two global functions, if I call function 2 from within function 1, Can I access local code from function 1 within function 2

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner and have a simple question I really hope someone can help me with.  I have two global functions (a and b).  I have called function b within function a.  How Can I access local code within function a from function b without using global variables or parameters?

**Example:**

```
function a() {
    var x= 5
    b()
}
function b() {
    var y= 8 + x
}
```

Comment: no - because of [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

Comment: Why don't you test it and see?

Comment: What do you mean by "access local code"?

Comment: Well... https://jsfiddle.net/f2mcnx2w/1

Comment: JavaScript (fortunately) has *lexical scope* instead of [*dynamic scope*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping)

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass `x` as parameter to function `b(x)` as below.

```js
function a() {
    var x = 5;
    b(x);
}

function b(x) {
    var y = 8 + x;
  console.log(y);
}

a();
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can do it by handling function parameters, You can pass too many arguments by using Objects

**Example:**

```js
function a() {
    var x= 5,other_variable=100;
    var objectsOfB = b({x:5,other_variable:other_variable}); /*Pass your object/variables to function b()*/
    console.log(objectsOfB);   /*All variable from function b()*/
}

function b(objectsOfA) {
    console.log(objectsOfA);   /*All variables from function a()*/
    var y= 8 + objectsOfA.x;
    var more_variable = 200;
    return {y:y,more_variable:more_variable};              /*Return all variable from function b() to function a()*/
}

a();
```

> **Note:** From above code, You can use both function's local variables to each other function by returning variables as Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do *explicitly* what you're referring to, by creating a closure and passing scope back out into a `b` variable function. Essentially, since `b` is the returned function from within `a`, it retains scope to `x`, although `x` is still not available within the outer containing scope:

```js
function a() {
  var x = 10;

  return function(){
    x++;

    console.log(x);
  };
}

var b = a();

b(); // 11
b(); // 12
b(); // 13
b(); // 14

// Not defined in this scope.
try {
  console.log('x:', x);
} catch(e) {
  console.log('Exception! ', e);
}
```

In your case, I'm sure you just want to pass it as a variable to `b` like `b(x)` or

```
function a(){return 5;}
function b(x){console.log(x + 8);}
b(a());
```